# Recursive Functions - Factorial

Tags: python, function, recursion, factorial

I am totally new to recursive functions and tried to create a function to compute the factorial of n. In my example I assume n > 0.

```
def myfactorial(n):
    if (n - 1) > 0:                       # Check if n - 1 is > 0
       return ( n * myfactorial(n - 1) )  # Then multiply current n with myfactorial(n - 1)
    else:
        return                            # If condition is false, then stop function
```

However, it the error `unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'` for the line `return ( n * myfactorial(n - 1) )`.

When looking at the solution from [w3resource.com](https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/python-functions-exercise-5.php)

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n - 1)
```

They use the same return idea in the statement as I.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in my approach (by the way, I designed the if statement on purpose as n-1 > 0, nevertheless it has to work with this statement as well)?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: because 0>0 will fail and in else it will return None

Comment: What do you think `myfactorial(1)` returns in your function?

Comment: Your definition says that `1! == None`. That's not true; `1! == 1`. (In fact, `0!` is defined to be `1`, so you can use `n == 0` as your base case.)

Comment: (Depending on how robust you want the function to be, you can also have a base case for negative `n` to avoid infinite recursion and for non-numeric `n` to avoid `TypeError`s.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `return` it's have the same effect as `return None`.

When you do `myfactorial(1)`, you return `None`. With `myfactorial(2)`, you do `2 * myfactorial(1)`, which is equivalent to `2 * None`, which trigger the error :

```
unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

That why you have to write `return 1` in your else branch.

Comment: Thank you iElden and Deepak Tripathi. You are absolutelty right. I especially did not take the n = 0 case into account. This of course has to output 1.